# Is this a run-on?: does "by which" create a subordinate clause?

Tags: sentence-construction

Sentence in question:

> Myths are often marked by anthropomorphism, the concept by which animals and inanimate forces are invested.

The quote above has two subjects and is not separated by a conjunction. Does "by which" make the second clause subordinate?

Comment: if by which makes the second clause subordinate then the sentence is not a run-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a run-on sentence, since *by which* introduces a subordinate clause.

However, the sentence feels incomplete.  Perhaps it should read

> Myths are often marked by anthropomorphism, the concept by which animals and inanimate forces are invested **with human attributes**.

Comment: what are other subordinate conjunctions related to "which"?

Comment: what are some other not-obvious subordinating conjunctions?